# How to add or remove quantity cart django and also in templates?

Tags: python, django

**Views.py**

```
def cart_home(request):
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    return render(request, "carts/home.html", {"cart": cart_obj})

def cart_update(request):
    product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
    if product_id is not None:
        try:
            product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            print("Expired product")
            return redirect("cart:home")
        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
        if product_obj in cart_obj.products.all():
            cart_obj.products.remove(product_obj)
        else:
            cart_obj.products.add(product_obj)
        request.session['cart_items'] = cart_obj.products.count()
    return redirect("cart:home")
```

**models.py**

```
class CartManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self, request):
        cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id", None)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id=cart_id)
        if qs.count() == 1:
            new_obj = False
            cart_obj = qs.first()
            if request.user.is_authenticated() and cart_obj.user is None:
                cart_obj.user = request.user
                cart_obj.save()
        else:
            cart_obj = Cart.objects.new(user=request.user)
            new_obj = True
            request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
        return cart_obj, new_obj

def new(self, user=None):
    user_obj = None
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_authenticated():
            user_obj = user
    return self.model.objects.create(user=user_obj)

class Cart(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)`enter code here`
    products    = models.ManyToManyField(CartItem, blank=True)
    subtotal    = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=65, decimal_places=2)
    total       = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=65, decimal_places=2)
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = CartManager()
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)



def m2m_changed_cart_receiver(sender, instance, action, *args, **kwargs):
    if action == 'post_add' or action == 'post_remove' or action == 'post_clear':
        products = instance.products.all()
        total = 0
        for x in products:
            total += x.price
        if instance.subtotal != total:
            instance.subtotal = total
            instance.save()

m2m_changed.connect(m2m_changed_cart_receiver, sender=Cart.products.through)



def pre_save_cart_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.subtotal > 0:
        instance.total = float(instance.subtotal)  * float(1.15) #8% tax
    else:
        instance.total = 0.00

pre_save.connect(pre_save_cart_receiver, sender=Cart)
```

**As the original poster did not format the code correctly he avoided the validation error 'It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.'.**

Comment: Please properly format your question so that the code is readable. Use the tools provided by SO. Also don't just post code, please explain your problem. What are your trying to do, what does your code currently do, what errors or wrong behavior do you see?

Comment: Did you eventually resolve your problem?